# How to redirect any response to an arbitrary location in OWASP ZAP's request editor?

Tags: owasp, zap

I am trying to find *stored XSS* in an application. Luckily, the application allows me to insert and edit the description of myself that is displayed to anyone visiting my profile.

The location where I edit my description: http://example/edit_desc?content=test

Page where the edited description is displayed: http://example/user

Coming to my problem, how can I configure zap's request editor in such a way that when I send request in the http://example/edit_desc?content=test, the response for http://example/user is displayed?

**NOTE:** One possible thing I thought of was to include `Location: http://example/edit_dec?content=test` as header of every response but figured out no way to do it in the `Request editor`.

Answer (score 1):

edit: working solution below!

I would look at building a proxy rule script to check for the URL path being called, and then make a call to the 'response' path.

Examples:
https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpAddonsScriptsScripts

Here is the example template for proxy scripts:
https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/proxy
and the corresponding documentation for the HTTPMessage object that you'd be handling:
https://www.zaproxy.org/2.5/javadocs/org/parosproxy/paros/network/HttpMessage.html

---

**simple solution**

I don't work with javascript(mostly a python guy), but let's see if we can work through a basic script:

Here's the example JS proxy script template linked above:

```
/**
 * This function allows interaction with proxy responses (i.e.: 
inbound from the server to the browser/client).
 * 
 * @param msg - the HTTP response being proxied. This is an HttpMessage object.
 */
function proxyResponse(msg) {
// Debugging can be done using print like this
    print('proxyResponse called for url=' + 
msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().toString())
    return true
}
```

So if we want to go somewhere else, we can try a 307(temporary redirect) like so:

```
function proxyRequest(msg) {
return true
}

function proxyResponse(msg){
    print(msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().toString());
    if (msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().toString().contains("edit_desc?content=")) {
        print("Found the URL!");
        var uri = msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().toString()
        var username = uri.match(/content=(.*)/)[1];
        var redirUrl = "http://example.com/"+username;
        msg.getResponseHeader().setStatusCode(307);
        msg.getResponseHeader().setHeader("Location", redirUrl)
    return true;
    }
}
```

If you throw that in a new proxy script(if you're having trouble with it not letting you make a new script, duplicate another and replace everything), enable it, and voila, it redirects any requests with `'edit_desc?content='user` to `'http://example.com/user'` **after** submitting the request to the server.

**script in action**

script enabled:

[image: script]

request in history:
[image: request_history]

response view:

[image: response]

browser state:

[image: browser]

Comment: Can you please approve the edit ? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It's working but only in requests made by the proxy. It is neutral to any requests made from the `Request Editor`. For that to work in `Request Editor`, the script has to be belonging to the `HTTP Sender` instead of `HTTP Proxy`. For that the script posted above requires tweaks and changes but it's similar.